# XPATH - How to get text from a webpage?

Tags: java, javascript, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to select the particulr text from webpage using XPATH.
My Text looks like below

```
The "Add Account Offer" request has been submitted successfully with the order number css_334560.
```

In the above line i need to get only "css_334560" using XPATH. Can someone help me here?

HTML :-

```
<div id="secondColumn" class="floatBreaker">
<div id="mainContents">
<h1>Add Account Offers                     </h1>
<div class="infoBox">
<div class="topLine">
<div class="txtLineRight">
<div class="txtLineLeft">
<div class="txt">
<span>The "Add Account Offer" request has been submitted successfully with the order number css_334560.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You won't get only `css_334560` using Selenium rather you'll get entire text in span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code if you use Java:

```
String a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='txt']/span")).getText(); 
a = a.substring(a.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1).replace(".", "");
```

First row gets text from span. Second row takes `css_334560.` and removes dot.

Html code is not full, so I can't guaranty that xpath is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities which depends on the situation.

1- Getting a text node that includes a certain text:
I used "Add Account Offer" but you can use "css_" or any other text that would be unique to that text node.

If there are a few matching text nodes: (get them and loop through them, checking them one by one)

```
var snapElements = document.evaluate(
    './/text()[contains(.,"Add Account Offer")]',
    document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

If there is only ONE matching text node

```
var txt = document.evaluate(
    './/text()[contains(.,"Add Account Offer")]',
    document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
```

2- On the other hand, if `<div class="txt">` is unique (there is only one on the page), if it faster to get it by:

```
var txt = document.querySelector('.txt');
if (txt) { txt = txt.textContent; }
```

Also possible ...

```
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('txt');
if (txt[0]) { txt = txt[0].textContent; }
```

After getting the whole text, now you can use (for example) a RegEx to get the desired section ... for example:

```
var css = txt.match(/css_\d+/);
```

Good luck 
:)

Comment: The only problem with this answer is the context - Selenium. Selenium expects physical DOM elements to be returned from a given XPath selector, your first two XPath's won't return a DOM element.

Comment: Thank you Arran ... I am not familiar with Selenium so my answer was based on standard HTML/DOM :)